# Authentication Route Problem Laravel Only on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-middleware

I am running a Laravel project on Windows and Ubuntu. On Ubuntu, authentication doesn't work. When I entered the correct username and password, I was directed to the `home` page (route with the name `login`). However, on Windows it can run well, which is directed to the `dashboard` page.

LoginController.php

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('login');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
 
        
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
        }
 
        return back()->withErrors([
            'username' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
            'password' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ]);
    }

}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
})->name('login');

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate']);

Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard')->middleware('auth');
```

In Windows i use XAMPP (PHP 8.2.1) and Laravel 9.42. In Ubuntu i use PHP 8.1.7 and Laravel 9.42 without XAMPP. How to fix this on Ubuntu?

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Any Exceptions thrown? Anything in the log? Any debug output you can add?

Comment: no exception error, it just wrong routing for auth attempt.

Comment: Your home route is named `login` ?  and can you check the SESSION_DRIVER inside .env , just a trial, try to set it as `file` , clear config cache and try login again.

Comment: SESSION_DRIVER has already set to ```file```. Even if i set login page to named ```login```, i just redirected to login page again.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is any cache issue, just run the following commands and check it.

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: I've done it but still can't be resolved